# JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.javers() not getting called

Tags: spring, audit-trail, javers

## Context

I have used `@TypeName("Employee")` for my entities so I can lose the fully qualified TypeName in DB. It works as expected.

## Issue

When the Spring boot application is restarted and there are existing audit logs, I get **TYPE_NAME_NOT_FOUND** exception when I hit `javers.findSnapshots()`

`org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: TYPE_NAME_NOT_FOUND type name 'Employment' not found. If you are using @TypeName annotation, remember to register this class using JaversBuilder.scanTypeName(Class). See also https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/263`

## My Approach so far

- I have added [JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-spring-boot-starter-sql/src/main/java/org/javers/spring/boot/sql/JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.java), call it `MyJaversSqlAutoConfiguration`.
- I then added `scanTypeName(Employee.class)` in `MyJaversSqlAutoConfiguration.javers()`.

## Observation

- I noticed `MyJaversSqlAutoConfiguration.javers(connectionProvider)` doesn't get hit. However, `org.javers.spring.boot.sql.JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.javers()` gets hit in debug mode. commitPropertiesProvider() and springSecurityAuthorProvider() in `MyJaversSqlAutoConfiguration' gets hit. But not`MyJaversSqlAutoConfiguration.javers(ConnectionProvider connectionProvider)`.

Upon closer inspection, I found that `org.javers.spring.boot.sql.JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.javers()` doesn't have `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` but `commitPropertiesProvider()` and `springSecurityAuthorProvider()` do.

## Question

Is there a working example of this scanTypeName() somewhere or should we add @ConditionalOnMissingBean?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is missing in javers bean defintions (in both `javers-spring-boot-starters`).

It can be added to `JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.java` and `JaversMongoAutoConfiguration.java`

```
@Bean(name = "javers")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public Javers javers(ConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
...
```

If you contribute a PR, we will merge it.